# Object not found in xampp (running apache service)

Tags: xampp

Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 404

localhost
Apache/2.4.17 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2d PHP/5.6.14

**i did run apache service and mysql and i have htdocs in xampp, also having index.php...
help?**

**also, while i'm trying to make sure i installed everything (i followed wikihow tutorial) i clicked on the mysql admin section and it leads me to http://localhost/phpmyadmin/ but when i click on the apache admin it just leads me to http://localhost/dashboard/...**

i created new folder named try inside xampp and tried again my code was

```
<?php
echo "<h1>hey, buddy!</h1>";
?>
```

i called this hi.php

localhost/try/hi.php

**then tried to access it but... nothing**

Comment: What address are you trying to access?

Comment: read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @BrendanAbel, xampp/index.php (inside htdocs)